# AngularFire2: query if child exists

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2

I'm planning on fetching a list from my database, where certain records contain a property that may be set. I want to query and display items which  don't have this property

```
{
  books: {
    book_3: {
     title: "Return of The King"
    },
    book_2: {
     title: "The Two Towers"
    },
    book_1: {
     title: "The Fellowship of the Ring"
     read: 1256953732
    }
  }
}
```

I've read the first book and I want to display the remaining two books.
In Firebase I do:

```
fbl.child('books').orderByChild('read').equalTo(null).on("value", function(data) { 
 // handle data
}
```

And in AngularFire2 I would do something like:

```
this.af.database.list('books', { query: {
  orderByChild: 'read',
  equalTo: null
}});
```

The first way works and I get book_2, book_3, but the AngularFire2 way returns the whole list! Is there a value that can be indicated as a null value? I've tried booleans, empty strings etc. but nothing seems to work.

Perhaps this is a bug.

Comment: I had the same issue

Comment: It could be argued that it's a bug, as [this](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/2.0.0-beta.6/src/database/query_observable.ts#L195-L197) is the test that's applied to the `equalTo` option. If `null` is a sensible value that's useful with the SDK, it should really only be ignoring `undefined`. I'd raise an [issue](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues).

Comment: @cartant issue raised: [704](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/704)

Answer (score 1):

<s>The problem has been fixed with [this pull request](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/pull/715) - which was included in the `2.0.0-beta.7` release of AngularFire2.</s>

The problem has been fixed with [this pull request](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/pull/809) - which should be included in the published version of AngularFire2 that follows `2.0.0-beta.7`.

With the fix, if you create queries like this:

```
this.af.database.list('books', { query: {
  orderByChild: 'read',
  equalTo: null
}});
```

They will behave as you would expect them to and will return only the list items that don't have `read` properties.

Comment: has there been any changes lately that breaks this. I'm getting full list again, not with `null` eleminiation.

Comment: "null elimination" is wrong term, but you get the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could just populate the "read" child of every node with 0 ( as you are storing the timestamp and its an integer value) and query something like this:

```
   af.database.list('books', { query: {
orderByChild: 'read', 
    equalTo: 0
    }
```